# À quoi réfèrent « la première » et « la deuxième » dans ce contexte ?

Tags: expressions, pronoms, nombres

Je voudrais savoir ce que représentent les expressions « la première » et « la deuxième » dans ce contexte (*[Le sexuel et le social. Lecture anthropologique](http://classiques.uqac.ca/contemporains/balandier_georges/sexuel_et_social/sexuel_et_social_texte.html)* de Georges Balandier dans les *Cahiers internationaux de sociologie*, vol. 76, janvier-juin 1984, pp. 5-19):

> La réglementation sexuelle définit des femmes « interdites » et des femmes « permises ».  Ces distinctions délimitent ce qui relève de la conformité et ce qui, à l'inverse, provoque l'irruption de la transgression.  La première est appréhendée comme fondée en nature et en culture, et la seconde, pour cette même raison, est reconnue doublement néfaste.

Answer (score 4):

C'est ce qui distingue d'une part les femmes « interdites » et d'autre part les femmes « permises » évoquées dans la première phrase de l'extrait:

> Première distinction : « ce qui relève de la conformité »
>
> Deuxième distinction : « ce qui provoque l'irruption de la transgression »